# WPS getting lowest n results

Tags: wps, ogc-api

I am very new to WPS and currently playing around with the WPS Request-Builder.
I would like to receive the top x highest or lowest features by a given attribute.
I have been trying to achieve this by vec:Query and adding filters. I imagined a combination of sortBy and maxfeatures - but these seem to be strict WMS vendor parameters and not available for this kind of WPS requests.